# vue3-cookies and Vue composition api strange mistake?

Tags: vue.js, cookies, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have followed the tutorial on the npm official site for [vue3-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-cookies)  and in the composition API, I got a strange and not clear (for me) bug?

```
import { useCookies } from "vue3-cookies";

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

const { cookies } = useCookies();
```

This error is not clear to me, and I am not totally sure how to fix this, thank you!

Comment: How you use `cookies` object?.

Comment: Just following the tutorial in the link above...

Comment: Please, refer to tutorials for informative purposes only. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It shouldn't depend on the availability and changes in external links. It's unknown what exactly you try and how it differed from the suggested link. In case there's an error, please, post the complete error including call stack. You can also navigate to the place where the error occurred and show it, something that other users won't be able to do